# PHPExcel, Date being parsed incorrectly

Tags: php, date, format, phpexcel

Currently, I'm making a program for my job that uses PHPexcel to basically take all of the data from an excel sheet, make a new excel sheet and format it to text, and transfer all of the data from the old excel sheet.

My php has to be able to take in the values from the old excel sheet and parse them correctly, especially dates/numbers/etc.

Everything is working fine except for the dates. For some reason when I get the formatted value of the cell; it does not match the date format in the first sheet. Specifically a value like this: 12/31/2099 . For some reason, it reads the formatcode incorrectly as mm-dd-yy and outputs 12-31-99. This is extremely frustrating and I've scoured half of the internet for an answer. Help please; I'm not sure what the issue is! Code:

```
<?php
$spreadSheet=$_FILES["filebrowser"]["tmp_name"];
/** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/Shared/Date.php';
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
//Create temporary sheet from uploaded file data
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($spreadSheet);
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setTitle("Original Data");
$data=$sheet->getCell("D9")->getFormattedValue();

var_dump($data);
exit;?>
```

D9 is a cell with DATE format and a value of 12/31/2099. This code prints 12-31-99...

Comment: Try getValue() instead of getFormattedValue()

Comment: getValue() gets the raw data value of the cell and returns a float.

Comment: From what I can tell here (http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/371418) you should be able to then use Date::Time to convert it to the date format you want.

Comment: Yes, but when I get the format code from the cell, it returns a format code of mm-dd-yy instead of the correct format... So if I try to do something like this, it doesn't work:
 $s= $sheet->getCell("D9")->getValue();
$d=PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($s);
$form=$sheet->getStyle("D9")->getNumberFormat()->getFormatCode();
var_dump(date($form,$d));

Comment: Use the PHP Date::Time object, not the PHPExcel functions once you have $s, or try date('m-d-Y',$s)

Comment: that's part of the problem, I can't explicitly define the format for the user, I need the format to be able to be generic based on what the user has given via excel.

Comment: make sure the integer version of your date isn't overflowing PHP_MAX_INT

Comment: Doing this results in an incorrect date as well var_dump(date("m/d/Y",$d)); output=  "11/24/1963"

Comment: max int shouldn't be a problem as I also tried floatval(PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($s) and doubleval

Answer (score 6):

Using PHPExcel v1.7.9

Open file 
**"PHPExcel\Style\NumberFormat.php"**

Go to Line 278:

```
self::$_builtInFormats[22] = 'm/d/yy h:mm';
```

replace with

```
self::$_builtInFormats[22] = 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm';
```

or whatever format you want.

I can't find an efficient way to change it on the fly and I have no reason to ever format the date in any way other than this so this solution works for me.

Comment: I was having the same exact issue, this answer was the closest / easiest one.  The line number that needs to be changed is self::$_builtInFormats[14] = 'mm-dd-yy'; to: self::$_builtInFormats[14] = 'mm/dd/yyyy';

Comment: Thanks for such nice answer @steve
but for me works line no 270
self::$_builtInFormats[14] = 'mm-dd-yy'; to: self::$_builtInFormats[14] = 'yyyy-mm-dd'

Answer (score 2):

Using v1.7.8 and assuming Excel2007 aka `.xlsx` file

```
$a1Cell = $sheet->getCell('A1');
$a1CellFormattedValue = trim($a1Cell->getFormattedValue());
if (!empty($a1CellFormattedValue)) {
    $dateInTimestampValue = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($a1Cell->getValue());
}
```

Let me explain each line.

- line 1 is to get the Cell object
- line 2 and the if block is so that we only perform for non-empty cells
- line 4 is how we transform the value inside the cell into unix timestamp.

You're left with deciding what date formats to write the value into the destination excel file. My suggestion is that you decide with the stakeholders that ALL dates in destination excel files will follow a particular format.

This is the cleanest way I can think of.

P.S. If you have an empty cell, and you try to do the `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP` on the cell value, you will get the current date.

**UPDATE**

Just realized that your comments mention you cannot arbitrarily decide the format. Sorry about that. If I come across something that helps, I will update this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across your question.
if you know the format in which excel is saving date, then you can use the PHP class `DateTime` as an intermediate date representation

```
$data=$sheet->getCell("D9")->getFormattedValue();
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat ("m-d-y" , $data);
$string_date = $date->format($format);
```

where `$format` is any format you want