# PHP Excel Date Issue

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am not new to PHP, but new to PHPExcel, using it for the first time.
So I preferred to just dump data from excel sheet into an array

```
$importData = $objImport->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
```

But the problem with this is that date values are returned in format mm-dd-yy, so,
year 2013 and 1913 are both returned as '13' in yy form. 
I would like to receive it in yyyy form.

Comment: the joys of excel's utterly screwy dates. use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to coerce those excel dates into native PHP ones.

Comment: Modify the number format masks for those date fields to give a 4 digit year: if the configured date mask for the cells only displays a 2-digit year anyway, then ask the provider of the workbook to change their formatting for dates if it's ambiguous

Comment: Might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/17635154/258674

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$fDate = $importData[1][C];
$fDate='10-29-14';
$fDate=  explode('-', $fDate);
$fDate=$fDate[1].'-'.$fDate[0].'-'.str_pad('14', 4, '20',STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo $fDate;// 29-10-2014
```